# How to calculate when inventory will run out using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a DataFrame like so:

```
Item        Check Date   Inventory
Apple       1/1/2020     50
Banana      1/1/2020     80
Apple       1/2/2020     75
Banana      1/2/2020     300
Apple       2/1/2020     100
Apple       2/2/2020     98
Banana      2/2/2020     341
Apple       2/3/2020     95
Banana      2/3/2020     328
Apple       2/4/2020     90
Apple       2/5/2020     85
Banana      2/5/2020     325
```

I want to find the average rate of change in the inventory for a given item starting from the max inventory count, then use that to compute what day the inventory will reach zero.
So for apples it would be starting from 2/1: `2+3+5+5/4 = 3.75`, similarly for bananas starting from 2/2 `13+3/2 = 8`.

Since there are different items, I have used:

`apples = df[df["Item"] == "apples"]`

to get a dataframe for just the apples, then used:

`apples["Inventory"].idxmax()`

to find the row with the max inventory count.

However, this gives me the row label of the row for the original dataframe. So I'm not sure where to go from here since my plan was to then get the date off the row with the max inventory count, then ignore any dates before that.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the `idxmax` but with `transform`

```
s=df[df.index>=df.groupby('Item').Inventory.transform('idxmax')]
out=s.groupby('Item')['Inventory'].apply(lambda  x : -x.diff().mean())
Item
Apple     3.75
Banana    8.00
Name: Inventory, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you thats seems to work okay.
Let's say I have an additional column for the variety of apple or banana. How would you go about calculating the rate per variety?